# Batch-wise beam search in pytorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, pytorch, beam-search

I'm trying to implement a beam search decoding strategy in a text generation model. This is the function that I am using to decode the output probabilities.

```
def beam_search_decoder(data, k):
    sequences = [[list(), 0.0]]
    # walk over each step in sequence
    for row in data:
        all_candidates = list()
        for i in range(len(sequences)):
            seq, score = sequences[i]
            for j in range(len(row)):
                candidate = [seq + [j], score - torch.log(row[j])]
                all_candidates.append(candidate)
        # sort candidates by score
        ordered = sorted(all_candidates, key=lambda tup:tup[1])
        sequences = ordered[:k]
    return sequences
```

Now you can see this function is implemented with batch_size 1 in mind. Adding another loop for batch size would make the algorithm `O(n^4)`. It is slow as it is now. Is there any way to improve the speed of this function. My model output is usually of the size `(32, 150, 9907)` which follows the format `(batch_size, max_len, vocab_size)`

Comment: The beam-search strategy has sense during test time. Can't you maintain a `batch_size=1` and parallelize the processing of the test examples?

Comment: You may also have a look at the [beam search implementation](https://github.com/aimagelab/meshed-memory-transformer/blob/master/models/beam_search/beam_search.py)  and code [in this repo](https://github.com/aimagelab/meshed-memory-transformer) for image captioning using a modified Transformer. The implementation makes use PyTorch's `register_buffer` to cache the inputs of the previous timestep, so that only the new input is fed in the current timestep and is considerably fast.

Answer (score 9):

Below is my implementation, which may be a little bit faster than the for loop implementation.

```py
import torch


def beam_search_decoder(post, k):
    """Beam Search Decoder

    Parameters:

        post(Tensor) – the posterior of network.
        k(int) – beam size of decoder.

    Outputs:

        indices(Tensor) – a beam of index sequence.
        log_prob(Tensor) – a beam of log likelihood of sequence.

    Shape:

        post: (batch_size, seq_length, vocab_size).
        indices: (batch_size, beam_size, seq_length).
        log_prob: (batch_size, beam_size).

    Examples:

        >>> post = torch.softmax(torch.randn([32, 20, 1000]), -1)
        >>> indices, log_prob = beam_search_decoder(post, 3)

    """

    batch_size, seq_length, _ = post.shape
    log_post = post.log()
    log_prob, indices = log_post[:, 0, :].topk(k, sorted=True)
    indices = indices.unsqueeze(-1)
    for i in range(1, seq_length):
        log_prob = log_prob.unsqueeze(-1) + log_post[:, i, :].unsqueeze(1).repeat(1, k, 1)
        log_prob, index = log_prob.view(batch_size, -1).topk(k, sorted=True)
        indices = torch.cat([indices, index.unsqueeze(-1)], dim=-1)
    return indices, log_prob
```

Comment: Shouldn't the indices be between 0 and vocab_size?  In this implementation, they are between 0 and vocab_size*k

Comment: You are right!
This returns indices from the flatten array (c.f. `log_prob.view`) which can exceed the vocabulary size. This version also overlooks sequences sharing a portion of tokens at their start.

Answer (score 1):

###### /!\ The most upvoted answer doesn't perform a correct beam-search!

Based on the version proposed by 防暴队大盾, I decided to implement a version of the beam-search algorithm that does not overlook sequences that share initial tokens. This is done by retrieving correct indices from the indices of the flatten array

```
def beam_search(prediction, k=10):
    batch_size, seq_length, vocab_size = prediction.shape
    log_prob, indices = prediction[:, 0, :].topk(k, sorted=True)
    indices = indices.unsqueeze(-1)
    for n1 in range(1, seq_length):
        log_prob_temp = log_prob.unsqueeze(-1) + prediction[:, n1, :].unsqueeze(1).repeat(1, k, 1)
        log_prob, index_temp = log_prob_temp.view(batch_size, -1).topk(k, sorted=True)
        idx_begin = index_temp // vocab_size  # retrieve index of start sequence
        idx_concat = index_temp % vocab_size  # retrieve index of new token
        new_indices = torch.zeros((batch_size, k, n1+1), dtype=torch.int64)
        for n2 in range(batch_size):
            new_indices[n2, :, :-1] = indices[n2][idx_begin[n2]]
            new_indices[n2, :, -1] = idx_concat[n2]
        indices = new_indices
    return indices, log_prob
```

This version assumes that `prediction` corresponds to the cross-entropy scores, not the probability. Therefore no need to take the log here.

If someone knows how to avoid the inner-most loop with some fancy indexing, one can probably make this even faster.

Answer (score -2):

You can use this library

https://pypi.org/project/pytorch-beam-search/

It implements Beam Search, Greedy Search and sampling for PyTorch sequence models.

The following snippet implements a Transformer seq2seq model and uses it to generate predictions.

```py
#pip install pytorch-beam-search
from pytorch_beam_search import seq2seq

# Create vocabularies
# Tokenize the way you need
source = [list("abcdefghijkl"), list("mnopqrstwxyz")]
target = [list("ABCDEFGHIJKL"), list("MNOPQRSTWXYZ")]
# An Index object represents a mapping from the vocabulary to
# to integers (indices) to feed into the models
source_index = seq2seq.Index(source)
target_index = seq2seq.Index(target)

# Create tensors
X = source_index.text2tensor(source)
Y = target_index.text2tensor(target)
# X.shape == (n_source_examples, len_source_examples) == (2, 11)
# Y.shape == (n_target_examples, len_target_examples) == (2, 12)

# Create and train the model
model = seq2seq.Transformer(source_index, target_index)    # just a PyTorch model
model.fit(X, Y, epochs = 100)    # basic method included

# Generate new predictions
new_source = [list("new first in"), list("new second in")]
new_target = [list("new first out"), list("new second out")]
X_new = source_index.text2tensor(new_source)
Y_new = target_index.text2tensor(new_target)
loss, error_rate = model.evaluate(X_new, Y_new)    # basic method included
predictions, log_probabilities = seq2seq.beam_search(model, X_new) 
output = [target_index.tensor2text(p) for p in predictions]
output
```